# How to check strict equality of floating numbers in jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

```
  it('returns the median for even number of grades', () => {
    const grades = [80, 90, 85, 110, 100, 60]
    const expectedMedian = 87.50
    const median = calculateMedian(grades)
    expect(median).toBe(expectedMedian)
  })
```

This test passes but I don't want, `87.5` to equal with `87.50`.

Comment: You don't want `87.5` to be equal to `87.50`? That doesn't make any sense. These are *the same number*. How can they be *anything but equal*?

Comment: I want those numbers to be displayed in a graph. And I want to check if unneeded trailing zeros are added.

Comment: There is `.toFixed()` in the `calculateMedian` code, so I want to test that.

Comment: Try convert it to string and compare it. When in number ```87.5``` and ```87.50``` are equal then ```87.5``` and ```87.50``` are not equal

Comment: @HenokTesfaye How do you determine if the trailing zeros are unneeded? If you don't want them *displayed* then trim them off the end of the string.

Comment: In that case you should use `expect(median).toStrictEqual("87.5")` to also verify that it returns a string and not a number.

Comment: Yes, `expect(median).toStrictEqual("87.5")` works. But no need to strict equal.

Comment: Why do you want to differenciate between 87.50 and 87.5?

Answer (score 2):

in numerics I've learned, that you rather want to check, whether the difference of two floating point numbers is below a (small) treshold.

See [Machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon).

So use [toBeLessThanOrEqual](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tobelessthanorequalnumber--bigint) of Jest here.